# Is there a way to make a Firebase search query case insensitive without using child?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This is my Firestore query in Dart:

```
getResults(){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').where("itemModel", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _searchQueryController.text.trim())
        .where("status", isEqualTo: "approved")
        .get()
        .then((results){
          setState(() {
            items = results;
          });
    });
  }
```

But it is case-sensitive. For example, if I have an `itemModel` called `"Checkboard"`, it won't show up if I search for `"checkboard"`(with a lower-case 'c'). How can I make it case insensitive without modifying the data stored in my Firestore database? Here's a picture of my Firestore Database for reference:
[Picture of Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z79N8.png)

Comment: Every time you searching something you have make your text also case sensitive by using `.toLowerCase()` ex: `_searchQueryController.text.toLowerCase().trim()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All queries in Firestore are case-sensitive.

If you need a case-insensitive mechanism you'll need to write a separate field that contains the case-insensitive version of the field and query against it. For instance:

```
db.collection("items").where("itemModel", "==", "Checkboard")
db.collection("items").where("lowercaseItemModel", "==", "checkboard")
```

There is a great answer from @DanMcGrath that I recommend you read:

- [Cloud Firestore Case Insensitive Sorting Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query/48098215#48098215)

Or an alternative from @samthecodingman:

- [Is there a way to search In Firebase firestore without saving another field in lowercase for case-insensitive search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364761/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-firebase-firestore-without-saving-another-field-in-l)