# Flutter firebase search query without case sensitivity

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a search bar where I can search data from Firestore. But with this it is case-sensitive. How can I change it so it's case-insensitive?

```
var name = "";
final data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();

if (data["name].toString.startWith(name.toLowerCase().trim())){
                 return ....
                } //With this I can search data which ONLY start with lowerCase

if (data["name].toString.startWith(name.trim())){
                 return ....
                } //With this I can search data that starts with any Case but according to the Case I input. That is, if I start with upperCase, only data starting with upperCase appear and vice versa
```

I also tried removing the `.trim()` in both instances but the same result.

What can I do do the search query is insensitive to cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All queries in Cloud Firestore are case-sensitive. If you need a case-insensitive mechanism, then you'll need to create a separate field that contains the case-insensitive version of the field and query against it.

There is also a great answer from @DanMcGrath that I recommend you check:

- [Cloud Firestore Case Insensitive Sorting Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query/48098215#48098215)

Or an alternative answer from @samthecodingman:

- [Is there a way to search In Firebase firestore without saving another field in lowercase for case-insensitive search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364761/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-firebase-firestore-without-saving-another-field-in-l)

One last thing to mention is that the `trim()` function returns a string, with the leading and trailing whitespace omitted. It has nothing to do with case-sensitive or case-insensitive.

Comment: Could please tell me how make a TextField to ALWAYS start with upperCase automatically not matter the case the user inputs

Comment: You can do that on the client, meaning that you should read the first character of the string and make it upper case, or you can create a Cloud Function that should fire each time a new document is added, and create the same logic but on the server side.